# Unexpected Behavior for Visualforce Pages on Lightning page

Tags: inline-visualforce

I am having a major issue with the embedded VF page (via an installed Managed Package) on my Opportunity Object layouts.  I am using the Lightning Experience.

1) In Create New or Edit Mode - the record if not touched jumps down to the embedded VF Page.

2) If on the Details tab, the record, jumps down to the embedded VF page (even if there is data present).

Can this be disabled?  Can the VF not show up in Edit/Create mode in Lightning?

```
   <apex:page standardController="Opportunity" showHeader="false"   docType="html-4.01-strict">
   <CRMC_PP:Grid ObjectName="Custom_Object__c" FKName="Opportunity__c" FKValue="{!Opportunity.Id}"  DelayLoad="false"  ViewID="a0aP0000003IJC4IAO" 
    EnableNewButton="false"  EnableNewInline="false"  EnableEdit="false"  EnableActions="false"  EnableFieldChooser="false" 
    EnableStickyViews="false"  EnableToolbar="false"  EnableViews="false"  EnableFormatting="false"  EnableReadingPane="false" />
    <CRMC_PP:DrillUp />
    </apex:page>
```

Comment: did you any solution I am facing the exact same issue.